# Get related object has_and_belongs_to_many in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

Let's say I got tasks and lists with an has_and_belongs_to_many relationship:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :due_date
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lists
end


class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :user_id, :space_free_title
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks
end
```

Also I got the related model/table since a task can be on many lists:

```
class ListsTasks < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :list_id, :task_id
end
```

Now I know how to get all ListsTasks by the list_id:

```
ListsTasks.find_all_by_list_id(1)
```

But how do I get the contents of a task based on ListsTasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ListsTasks` model is unnecessary and is not being used by the two associations in your `List` and `Task` models.

Are you looking for something like `List.find(1).tasks` to get the tasks on that list?

Comment: Kinda, but since a task could be on list 1 and list 2 `List.find(1).tasks` would allow a task just to be on either list 1 oder list 2, right?

Comment: No. HABTM means that tasks can be on any number of lists, and lists can have any number of tasks. The code I provided will look up a list by its ID (1) and then give you all the tasks on it.

Comment: But that's exacly what I want. Say I got a task called **buy food for the party**.  Want that task to be on the **shopping**-list and on the **party**-list. And the task **buy lego** could be on the **birthday presents**-list and also on the **shopping**-list

Comment: And that's fine, I'm not telling you to change it. I'm simply telling you how to get tasks for a list, because I thought thats what the question was asking. If its not, what on earth are you asking?

Comment: I know, sorry if I did express my problem on an impolite way. :/ But why is `ListsTasks` unnecessary?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association note no reference to a join model at all. The table `lists_tasks` is necessary, the model for it is not.